# Seeking A Scale-Independent Alternative To Q2 For Model Selection When The Response Varies Over Multiple Orders of Magnitude

Tags: regression, cross-validation, optimization, model-selection, metric

I am using constrained polynomial regression to predict y = f(x). I have prior knowledge about the relationship that allows me to add constraints to the optimization problem for the first and second derivatives of the polynomial. However, the knowledge is not perfect and I want to select the optimal constraints to use from a set of different constraints.

I have been using Q2 (7-fold cross-validation) to compare predictions from models generated under the different constraints. I keep the model whose constraints maximizes Q2. However, y can vary over 2 orders of magnitude. The 'best' set of constraints tends to be the set that explains the variability in the high-value responses at the expense of explaining the variability in the low-value responses. Is there a less-scale dependent way to compare the models?

The responses vary between 0.25 -> 25. I added 1000 to the actual / predicted values when calculating the sum of squares for Q2. This improves the prediction of the low-value responses by a fair bit, but it seems pretty arbitrary and also not something that could be generalized to predictions of other responses where I want to apply the same strategy.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are using a fixed polynomial regression instead of a flexible model with something like regression splines? Could you do a prior log transform on your $y$ values, as they all seem to be strictly positive?

Comment: @EdM I want the resulting polynomial to be continuous in the first/second derivative. The nature of the process means that there is always exactly 1 maxima before the process is stopped. In addition, there is always exactly 1 inflection point that occurs between the start of the process and the maxima. The only difference between the models is when the maxima / inflection point occur.